# Останавливается анимация в WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Есть такой эллипс:

```
<Ellipse Width="12" Height="12" StrokeThickness="2" Stroke="#FF303030">
    <Ellipse.Triggers>
        <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Ellipse.Loaded">
            <BeginStoryboard>
                <Storyboard>
                    <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Shape.StrokeThickness)"
                                     AutoReverse="True"
                                     RepeatBehavior="Forever"
                                     Duration="0:0:02"
                                     To="4"/>
                </Storyboard>
            </BeginStoryboard>
        </EventTrigger>
    </Ellipse.Triggers>
</Ellipse>
```

Находится он в `TabItem`. Сперва всё отлично, но после того, как переключиться на любой другой `TabItem`, а затем вернуться обратно - анимация останавливается.

Подскажите, как сделать так, чтобы эллипс продолжал анимироваться после возврата на вкладку с ним?

Comment: А как вы задаете вкладки? Я проверил сейчас вашу анимацию в такой конструкции `<TabItem Header="Вкладка 1">Elipse...</TabItem>` - анимация останавливалась. Но, если задать `<TabItem Header="Вкладка 1"><TabItem.Content>Elipse...</TabItem.Content></TabItem>` - анимация работает как надо. Честно, не знаю почему так, попробуйте, вдруг поможет.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ, Я делал как в первом описанном вами способе, дело в том, что в этом `TabItem` не только эллипс, но я попробую задать всё содержимое в `Content`, может и так получится. Спасибо за наводку.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ, проверил, не помогло. Как быть, что делать... Чувствую это как-то связанно с `RoutedEvent` в `EventTrigger`. К сожалению другие события не подходят в моём случае, нужно только `Loaded`.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ, это на 100% равноценные записи, проблема в другом :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

На самом деле анимация работает, но при каждом переключении вкладок она *стартует заново*. Тут и кроется проблема: в вашей анимации указана только позиция `To`, поэтому если при переключении текущая толщина границ близка к 4, то анимация будет *незаметна*, проблема усугубляется еще тем, что при каждом переключении стартовая толщина становится всё больше и больше.

Решение, как вы уже наверное догадались, простое — установить стартовое значение явно: `From="2"`

Comment: Как обычно, решение прямо под носом, или за ухом... Короче говоря там, куда и не думаешь смотреть :)

Comment: @ArthurEdgarov, просто вы рано сдались, надо было пару раз запустить и посмотреть что происходит :)